# How to highlight the differences between text in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I want to store model text type editions using instrument like [paper trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem and I want to see editions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21185479/revisions) green and red backgrounds to show what was added and removed since previous version of the text. How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: Start [here](https://github.com/samg/diffy)

Comment: You can use https://github.com/gtarnovan/simple_audit for audit. That will give nice view to show diffs, that will fulfill your requirements.

Comment: @VishnuAtrai this gem seems outdated.

Comment: @user2422869 I'll inspect this solution and will answer you

Comment: What have you already tried?